# Lagrange interpolation polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

Are the coefficients of lagrange interpolation polynomials, in natural numbers? Because  in every example that I solve, the coefficients are in natural numbers.

Comment: No. Many examples are for illustration purposes, not to test how well you can do arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply   